# wxWidgets-3.1.0 installation error ubuntu nstall_wxregex] Error 1

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I have followed these steps to install wxwidget3.1.0

```
cd /path/to/wxWidgets-3.1.0
mkdir release-build
./configure --prefix=/path/to/wxWidgets-3.1.0 --enable-shared=no --enable-stl=yes --enable-debug=no --with-gtk=2 --with-libjpeg=builtin --with-libpng=builtin --with-regex=builtin --with-libtiff=builtin --with-zlib=builtin --with-expat=builtin --without-libjbig --without-liblzma --without-gtkprint --with-libnotify=no --with-libmspack=no --with-gnomevfs=no --with-opengl=yes --with-sdl=no --with-cxx=11
make
```

then `make install`...
everything was fine till make.
when i call make install the process stops with error message as given

```
make install
mkdir -p /home/think-computational/wxWidgets-3.1.0/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /home/think-computational/wxWidgets-3.1.0/lib/libwxregexu-3.1.a /home/think-computational/wxWidgets-3.1.0/lib
/usr/bin/install: '/home/think-computational/wxWidgets-3.1.0/lib/libwxregexu-3.1.a' and '/home/think-computational/wxWidgets-3.1.0/lib/libwxregexu-3.1.a' are the same file
make: *** [Makefile:13986: install_wxregex] Error 1
```

please help me to succeed this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I had same problem.

Solution: parameter `--prefix` must be different path from path where you are doing make.

Or try `--prefix=$(pwd)` (install in same directory where compilation is done)